# gdal_translate fails to add raster to existing vector geopackage

Tags: gdal, gdal-translate, geopackage

I have an existing GeoPackage `soils.gpkg` with a single vector feature set.

I am attempting to use Gdal to add a tiff raster to the GeoPackage; however, it fails in the following way:

```
C:\Users\Me\Documents\Stuff\GIS> gdal_translate -of GPKG tiff_test_wgs84.tiff soils.gpkg -co APPEND_SUBDATASET=YES
0ERROR 1: sqlite3_exec(INSERT INTO gpkg_tile_matrix_set (table_name,srs_id,min_x,min_y,max_x,max_y) VALUES ('tiff_test_wgs84',-1,-77.42268164174656,38.75415988758648,-77.41131759799439,38.76552393133866)) failed: no such table: gpkg_tile_matrix_set
...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
ERROR 1: failed to prepare SQL INSERT OR REPLACE INTO 'tiff_test_wgs84' (zoom_level, tile_row, tile_column, tile_data) VALUES (5, 0, 0, ?): no such table: main.gpkg_tile_matrix
ERROR 1: failed to prepare SQL INSERT OR REPLACE INTO 'tiff_test_wgs84' (zoom_level, tile_row, tile_column, tile_data) VALUES (5, 0, 1, ?): no such table: main.gpkg_tile_matrix
ERROR 1: failed to prepare SQL INSERT OR REPLACE INTO 'tiff_test_wgs84' (zoom_level, tile_row, tile_column, tile_data) VALUES (5, 0, 2, ?): no such table: main.gpkg_tile_matrix
ERROR 1: failed to prepare SQL INSERT OR REPLACE INTO 'tiff_test_wgs84' (zoom_level, tile_row, tile_column, tile_data) VALUES (5, 0, 3, ?): no such table: main.gpkg_tile_matrix
```

Does Gdal not try to create the `gpkg_tile_matrix` and `gpkg_tile_matrix_set` tables? I know that it does when creating a fresh GeoPackage from the same tiff file.

As far as I know, I've supplied the [correct arguments](http://www.gdal.org/drv_geopackage_raster.html) to gdal_translate for appending a raster file to an existing GeoPackage.

I've verified that `soils.gpkg` is a valid GeoPackage, looked at it in QGis etc. No idea what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: How the soil.gpkg database is created?

Comment: Try if you can add raster into a copy made with GDAL `ogr2ogr -f gpkg soils_gdal.gpkg soils.gpkg`